# While loop checking for non-existent lists

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have created a function that references a list with further lists inside it. For each list within a list, the function completes an action specific to the respective list(which works). Each time it runs, a variable (that indicates which list to search in) is increased by 1. However, I cannot get my while loop to exit once there are no remaining lists, i receive: 
"IndexError: list index out of range"

My code:

```
def my_function(selected_list):
    i = 1
    while (selected_list[i] != None):
        if ...
        if ...
    i+=1
```

The length of lists that it has to work with are all variable in length. I have used len(selected_list) to count and give it a maximum through an if statement, however i would like the while statement to end once it has no more lists to read. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If this is an accurate representation of your code, try indenting the `i += 1` so that it's part of the `while` block.

Comment: is a for loop not a better call to achieve this ? so you can get rid of the counter

Comment: for item in selected_list:

Comment: You are missing the first entry of `selected_list`, as python starts indexing with `0`. What about using `while (i < len(selected_list)):` ?

Comment: Thanks @Hannebambel this is exactly what I was missing. I was previously using: while (i<list_length), with list_length = len(selected_list) after the function definition, however this was kind of cheating the while statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use nested for loops:

```
def my_function(selected_list):
    for sub_list in selected_list:
        for item in sub_list:
            # Do ...
```

Answer (score 0):

### Just loop through the lists in the `selected_list`:

It is simplest to just use a `for-loop` to go through each of the sub lists instead of trying to work through them by increasing the index until the index is out of range as you are.

```
def my_function(selected_list):
   for lst in selected_list:
      if ...
      if ...
```

The only scenario I can see where what you are doing could be an advantage would be if you wanted to know the current index of the sub list. This can be achieved in the more pythonic way with `enumerate`:

```
def my_function(selected_list):
   for index, lst in enumerate(selected_list):
      if ...    #these calculations can now use the variable index
      if ...
```

Hope this helps!